multiple endnotes and correct markers
With various packages such as footmisc, enotez and properties of certain document-classes it is possible to customize footnotes/endnotes and their corresponding markers. However, there is a problem regarding multiple endnotes and their markers where I haven’t found a solution for, yet. In the following MWE, I use the KOMA-script class scrbook and enotez. This question is related to endnotes, but the footnote-examples are given for distinction.
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-heading=\section*{#1}, backref=true}

\renewcommand*{\multfootsep}{,\thinspace}

\begin{document}
First example with footnotes.\footnote{One\label{1}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Two\label{2}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Three\label{3}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Four\label{4}}

\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote} \setcounter{endnote}{4}

Second Example with endnotes.\footnote{Five}\label{5}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Six}\label{6}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Seven}\label{7}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Eight}\label{8}

Third example with references to previous footnotes.\footref{1}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{4}

Fourth example with references to previous endnotes.\footref{5}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{6}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{8}

Fifth example with reference to previous endnotes and new endnotes.\endnotetext{Nine}\label{9}\endnotetext{Ten}\label{10}\endnotetext{Eleven}\label{11}\endnotetext{Twelve}\label{12}\footref{5}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{7}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{9}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{12}

\printendnotes
\end{document}


The first four examples are as I would like them: In the first two, a total of four footnotes and endnotes are printed and correctly referenced. In the following two examples, the \footref-mechanism allows to reference them post hoc, separated by a superscripted em-dash or KOMA-script’s \multiplefootnoteseparator, depending on which footnote/endnote one would like to reference.
What I would like in example five is to write multiple endnotes and have them separated by a dash without having to separate them by a comma in the first instance. Differing from packages such as footnoterange or fnpct, I would like to have a mechanism that allows for referencing endnotes that are not referenced in a consecutive order (the same as the fourth example.) Furthermore, I couldn’t make these packages work for endnotes. For a footnote this mechanism is not necessary, as they are always printed in a consecutive order anyway and a callback will always be post hoc (e.g. footnotes on pages 4, 8, 12 and 16 which are summarily called back upon on page 20).
However, depending on the specific text, references to multiple endnotes may occur when some of them have already been referenced and some of them will be referenced for the first time (the fourth example may have already referenced endnotes 5 and 6, whereas endnote 7 is not important for the moment and left out and endnote 8 is referenced for the first time).
The problem with \endnotetext and \endnotemark is that the contents are always immediately »forgotten« as soon as two consecutive endnotes are employed. At least I couldn’t get it to work in the MMW! The fifth example should show »5, 7, 9–12« instead of »5, 7, 8–8«.

Whenever you use \footnotetext or similar, you have to basically make sure the counter has the right value. So, here, you need to set the counter correctly so that the labels get written correctly to the .aux. Right now, you're getting 5 lines written for the same counter value (8) and so 4 of them are simply discarded. I'm surprised it doesn't give you a warning, but it seems to just drop them silently.

Correction: you need to step at least 2 counters: the standard endnote counter e.g. with \refstepcounter and the expl3 integer counter which enotez uses internally. This is a hazard of using expl3 in current packages, I think. It is non-obvious how to manage counters/integers.

@cfr: How do you step expl3?

See answer below. But I can't see immediately how to get the back references to link in a simple way, so I don't know how useful it is. I posted it because at least the forward references/links work OK. At least, I think so.

In case you are willing to consider postnotes as an alternative, you can get things working with the following (if I understood what you are trying to do, that is, of which I'm not sure):
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{postnotes}
\postnotesetup{heading=\section*{\pntitle}}

\renewcommand*{\multfootsep}{,\thinspace}

\begin{document}
First example with footnotes.%
\footnote{One\label{1}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Two\label{2}}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Three\label{3}}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Four\label{4}}

\setcounter{postnote}{4}

Second Example with endnotes.%
\postnote{Five\label{5}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnote{Six\label{6}}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnote{Seven\label{7}}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnote{Eight\label{8}}

Third example with references to previous footnotes.%
\footref{1}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{4}

Fourth example with references to previous endnotes.%
\postnoteref{5}\textsuperscript{–}\postnoteref{6}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnoteref{8}

Fifth example with reference to previous endnotes and endnotes.%
\postnoteref{5}\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnoteref{7}%
\multiplefootnoteseparator\postnote{Nine\label{9}}%
\textsuperscript{–}\postnote[nomark]{Ten\label{10}}%
\postnote[nomark]{Eleven\label{11}}\postnote{Twelve\label{12}}

\printpostnotes
\end{document}

Note that postnotes does not offer the traditional \...mark/\...text split, but with the option nomark one can set a \postnote without typesetting the mark, and then refer to it with \postnoteref. Hyperlinks work, both ways (just take care with placement, since the link anchor lies with the \postnote, not with \postnoteref).
The result:


I didn’t look into postnotes, yet, but after this answer, I did. For me, the code is intuitively easier to understand and the runtime is quicker which is why I decided to switch and accept this answer!

@Kubo Nice that you liked it. And, indeed, the difference in performance is expected (and part of the reason I wrote the package). enotez writes the full contents of the notes to the .aux file, which is read twice during compilation. postnotes stores the contents of the notes in variables, no external file involved.

Whenever you use \footnotetext or similar, you have to basically make sure the counter has the right value. So, here, you need to set the counter correctly so that the labels get written correctly to the .aux. Right now, you're getting 5 lines written for the same counter value (8) and so 4 of them are simply discarded. I'm surprised it doesn't give you a warning, but it seems to just drop them silently.
For enotez, the counter is endnote, so I first tried inserting
\refstepcounter{endnote}

before each \endnotetext. This changed things, but it still didn't work. Looking at the source for the package, this is because enotez is mostly written in expl3. So it uses a expl3 integer to keep track of notes internally. It then simply steps the endnote counter each time the integer is incremented, in order to satisfy the LaTeX 2e cross-referencing system.
The upshot of this is that you need to increment this internal integer as well.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
\refstepcounter{endnote}%

As far as I can tell, the package really isn't designed to be used this way. You can add text to an endnote, provided it is marked at some point, and everything should work. But if you never mark it - but only reference it - this mechanism is never invoked and the contents of the note are lost.
So, if you use this hack, you should understand that you're probably fighting the grain of the package, which makes things more likely to break in the future.
That said, the following seems to work so far as the cross-referencing format etc. is concerned (but see below),
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-heading=\section*{#1}, backref=true}

\renewcommand*{\multfootsep}{,\thinspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \newendnote { +m }
{% We're not using \endnote or \endnotemark so we need to step the counter manually ourselves
  \int_gincr:N \g__enotez_endnote_id_int
  \refstepcounter{endnote}
  \endnotetext{ #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
First example with footnotes.\footnote{One\label{1}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Two\label{2}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Three\label{3}}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Four\label{4}}

\renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote} \setcounter{endnote}{4}

Second Example with endnotes.\footnote{Five}\label{5}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Six}\label{6}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Seven}\label{7}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footnote{Eight}\label{8}

Third example with references to previous footnotes.\footref{1}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{4}

Fourth example with references to previous endnotes.\footref{5}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{6}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{8}

Fifth example with reference to previous endnotes and new endnotes.%
\newendnote{Nine}\label{9}%
\newendnote{Ten}\label{10}%
\newendnote{Eleven}\label{11}%
\newendnote{Twelve}\label{12}%
\footref{5}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{7}\multiplefootnoteseparator\footref{9}\textsuperscript{–}\footref{12}

\printendnotes
\end{document}

Low res. image for what it is worth:

Here's the 'but': but this breaks back referencing hyperlinks. Or, rather, it doesn't fix the broken back-links for all the endnotes.

How can I get back references to work? There doesn't seem to be anything missing from the .aux, but nor does there seem to be any other generated file containing analogues of the missing targets. So apparently they don't rely on information from a previous run ...? Would just creating targets with the right names work?
